# Converting ObjC Blocks to C# Lambdas

Tags: c#, objective-c, mono, xamarin.ios

I need some help converting an Objective-C block to C#.

Here is the source ObjC:

```
NSDate* addYear = [_calendar dateByAddingComponents:((^{
        NSDateComponents* components = [NSDateComponents new];
        components.month = 12;
        return components;
    })()) toDate:now options:0];
```

Now I tried the following in C#:

```
NSDate date = _calendar.DateByAddingComponents((() => {
            NSDateComponents components = new NSDateComponents();
            components.Month = 12;
            return components;
        })(), now, NSCalendarOptions.None);
```

To which I get the following compiler error: `Expression denotes a 'anonymous method' where a 'method group' was expected`.

Removing the parentheses around the lambda yields `Cannot convert 'lambda expression' to non-delegate type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDateComponents'`.

What is the correct C# syntax? I need to retain the closures as there are a lot more in the code base that I am porting.

Comment: what's the signature of the DateByAddingComponents method?

Comment: @SteveMitcham In Mono, it's taking an NSDateComponents object.

Comment: try removing the () after you define the lambda, so you last line would be ''}), now, NSCal....'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
        var date = calendar.DateByAddingComponents (
            new NSDateComponents () 
            {
                Month = 12
            },
            NSDate.Now,
            NSCalendarOptions.None);
```

EDIT: You might need a Func:

```
        Func<NSDateComponents> func = () => new NSDateComponents () { Month = 12 };

        date = calendar.DateByAddingComponents (func (), NSDate.Now, NSCalendarOptions.None);
```

Within the method:

```
        date = calendar.DateByAddingComponents (
            (new Func<NSDateComponents>(()=> new NSDateComponents () { Month = 12 }))(),
            NSDate.Now,
            NSCalendarOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the closure is intentional from the original developers from what I can tell. And there are a bunch of closures in the source I'm porting.

Comment: Ok. I edited the answer, I hope that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @SKall, exactly what I was after.